# How to abort old autocomplete requests when new one is sent

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

In a jquery ui autocomplete box, is there a way to cancel previous searches when the user types more characters?

I was hoping to be able to use something like [ajaxmanager](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager3/), but I don't see a way that I can.  The closest I've gotten is [this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/autocomplete-remote-data-race-condition) thread.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who stumbles here from Google...the bug was fixed in version 1.4.3.

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6060

Comment: To be a little more clear, `var xhr = $.ajax(...)` followed by `xhr.abort()` used to not work properly, but was fixed as you mention.